# Read notifications when touch button in BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Some days ago I have written this question: [Is possible to detect touches in MiBand 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42255344/is-possible-to-detect-touches-in-miband-2)

I discovered using Wireshark that when I pulse MiBand button, the band send a UUID code to the mobile device.

I modifed this sample https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt to capture this event and for example show a Toast in screen. But However hard I tried, I do not advance.

Methods onDescriptorRead() and onCharacteristicRead() never called.

How is the way to capture this special characteristic using GATT in Android?
Thanks a lot

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. Read and Notification are two different things; if the device shall send a notification, the CCCD of the service has to be configured for notification by the app before the app can be notified. onCharacteristicRead() is only called if you have issued a read request before, and onDescriptorRead() is the answer to a read CCCD request. None of these two read responses is involved here.